# How to assign privilage to dynamically created database on C panel phpmyadmin.... programmatically using php

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, cpanel, cpanel-xmlapi

Actually I want to create database on my server dynamically while running a web page using php. when code behind of web page got executed I found newly created database, Code for creating dynamic database working fine...

But problem is that I am unable to assign the required privilege of Read and write to the particular user of that database.

I tried below code snippet:

```
function createDb($cPanelUser,$cPanelPass,$dbName) {
                                        $buildRequest = "/frontend/x3/sql/addb.html?db=".$dbName;
                                        $openSocket = fsockopen('localhost',2082);
                                        if(!$openSocket) {
                                           return "Socket error";
                                           exit();
                                        }
                                        $authString = $cPanelUser . ":" . $cPanelPass;
                                        $authPass = base64_encode($authString);
                                        $buildHeaders  = "GET " . $buildRequest ."\r\n";
                                        $buildHeaders .= "HTTP/1.0\r\n";
                                        $buildHeaders .= "Host:localhost\r\n";
                                        $buildHeaders .= "Authorization: Basic " . $authPass . "\r\n";
                                        $buildHeaders .= "\r\n";
                                        fputs($openSocket, $buildHeaders);
                                        while(!feof($openSocket)) {
                                           fgets($openSocket,128);
                                        }
                                        fclose($openSocket);

                                    }





  function createUser($cPanelUser,$cPanelPass,$userName,$userPass) {

                                    $buildRequest = "/frontend/x3/sql/adduser.html?user=".$userName."&pass=".$userPass;

                                    $openSocket = fsockopen('localhost',2082);
                                    if(!$openSocket) {
                                        return "Socket error";
                                        exit();
                                    }

                                    $authString = $cPanelUser . ":" . $cPanelPass;
                                    $authPass = base64_encode($authString);
                                    $buildHeaders  = "GET " . $buildRequest ."\r\n";
                                    $buildHeaders .= "HTTP/1.0\r\n";
                                    $buildHeaders .= "Host:localhost\r\n";
                                    $buildHeaders .= "Authorization: Basic " . $authPass . "\r\n";
                                    $buildHeaders .= "\r\n";

                                    fputs($openSocket, $buildHeaders);
                                    while(!feof($openSocket)) {
                                        fgets($openSocket,128);
                                    }
                                    fclose($openSocket);
                                }







 function addUserToDb($cPanelUser,$cPanelPass,$userName,$dbName,$privileges) {

                                $buildRequest = "/frontend/x3/sql/addusertodb.html?user=".$userName."&db=".$dbName.$privileges;

                                $openSocket = fsockopen('localhost',2082);
                                if(!$openSocket) {
                                    return "Socket error";
                                    exit();
                                }

                                $authString = $cPanelUser . ":" . $cPanelPass;
                                $authPass = base64_encode($authString);
                                $buildHeaders  = "GET " . $buildRequest ."\r\n";
                                $buildHeaders .= "HTTP/1.0\r\n";
                                $buildHeaders .= "Host:localhost\r\n";
                                $buildHeaders .= "Authorization: Basic " . $authPass . "\r\n";
                                $buildHeaders .= "\r\n";

                                fputs($openSocket, $buildHeaders);
                                while(!feof($openSocket)) {
                                    fgets($openSocket,128);
                                }
                                fclose($openSocket);
                            }



 createDb('cpanelusername','cpanelpassword','dbname');
                            createUser('cpanelusername','cpanelpassword','dbusername','dbpassword');
                            addUserToDb('cpanelusername','cpanelpassword','dbusername','dbname','&ALL=ALL');
```

Please Help....